# The last value in Read.Line() StreamReader

Tags: c#

Tell me please, how can I do so that would only give the last meaning of this search.
At the moment, about 15 MessageBox.Show is opened.
How to make it so that only the latter would show?

For the fifth hour I am suffering with different variations. Nothing happens.

```
TextReader tr = null;
try
{
    File.Copy(SteamLogFilePath, tmpFile, true);
}
catch { }
try
{
     tr = new StreamReader(tmpFile);
     try
     {
         string line = null;
         while (true)
         {
             line = tr.ReadLine();
             if (line.Contains("RecvMsgClientLogOnResponse") && line.Contains("OK"))
             {
                 tmpSplit1 = line.Split(')');
                 string SteamIdbrut = tmpSplit1[1];
                 tmpSplit1 = SteamIdbrut.Split(']');
                 string SteamIdnet = tmpSplit1[0].Replace(" : [", "");
                 long steam32 = Convert.ToInt64((GetFriendID(SteamIdnet)));
                 MessageBox.Show((FromSteam32ToSteam64(steam32)).ToString());
              }
         }
     }
            catch { }
 }
 catch { }
 if (tr != null)
     tr.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger? This is the first thing to do when something impossible happens. Run it and check what is the code flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this instead:

```
string lastLine = File.ReadLines(tmpFile)
    .Where(line => line.Contains("RecvMsgClientLogOnResponse") && line.Contains("OK"))
    .LastOrDefault();

// rest of code to create the MessageBox
```

This code replaces all of your code from 2nd `try` to `tr.Close();`.